# Sublime Text Plugin : Adding python libraries

Tags: python, sublimetext2, text-editor, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm trying to write a sublime text plugin which would make some windows api calls. I did some research and found out that [this python library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) provides the API's that I need to use.

So, I'm trying to to use this library. When I add import statement for it in my sublime text plugin it gives me error

```
ImportError: No module named win32api
```

I'd assume that it's because sublime text comes with inbuilt python and I haven't actually installed these libraries on my system it's throwing up these errors. How do I add such libraries in my sublime plugin also How would I distribute such plugin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to use a third-party library in Sublime, you'll need to include it in your plugin directory, and you'll need to include the correct version for the Python you're working with - 2.6 for ST2, 3.3 for ST3. In order for the next step to succeed properly, install the version of Python you're targeting on your system from [python.org](http://python.org/download). For example, if you're working with ST3, make sure you install Python 3.3.2 on your system.

Then, download the correct version of `pywin32` from Christoph Gohlke's [Python Extension Packages for Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32) repository. Install it on your system, then try copying `c:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\win32\` to your `Packages/MyPlugin` folder in Sublime. The installer makes several directories in `site-packages`, so depending on the system calls you're planning on making you might need to copy other directories as well - `win32com`, `win32comext`, `pywin32_system32`, and/or `pythonwin`.

You should now be able to `import win32` or `import .win32` in your plugin. Good luck!