# Use C# Class library as Plugin instead of Python Plugin in Sublime Text

Tags: c#, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have been using Sublime Text since version 1 but it was not untill last 2 weeks that i started to fully explore all the features of the editor.

I wanted to know if there would be any way to use a CSharp Class library as Plugin for Sublime Text.
Normally we write Python [.py] Plugins and assign Keybindings to various Commands that we write in the Python Plugin file.

I have been a DotNet developer since past 5 years and am totally new to Python so this functionality to use CSharp DLL files as Plugin would be a boon for me.

Any idea or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only develop plug-ins for Sublime Text using Python, as it says on the [plugin documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/plugins.html). So you cannot call methods in .NET DLLs directly from Python.

> You can write plugins for Sublime Text in Python

However, you can create a proxy .NET application (like a console app) which wraps the functionality of your .NET DLLs. You can call that app via the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module of Python. Your mileage will vary depending on what kind of functionality your DLLs have though.

Answer (score 0):

@vape [is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19972592/1426065), plugins must be written in Python. However, it is fairly straightforward to call programs written in other languages, for example using the `subprocess` module as mentioned. In addition to that, you may wish to check out [`pywin32`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32), as it provides many more methods for "natively" interacting with Windows, DLLs, etc. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19800737/1426065) of mine for more details on getting it set up in Sublime.

Composed properly, you should be able to construct your DLLs in such a way that their classes/methods/etc. are available in Python. This will allow you to program the majority of your logic in C#, and just use Python as a wrapper to pass and receive data. Depending on what exactly you're trying to do with your plugins, you may need to write some translation functions to properly handle the various [Sublime objects](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html) (ST3 link), but in my experience this shouldn't be too terribly difficult.

Good luck!