# How to import relative Python package (pycrypto)

Tags: python, import, sublimetext3, pycrypto

I am new to Python (as of today) and having trouble following this example for AES: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto/2.6.1 using Python 3.3

`from Crypto.Cipher import AES`

I downloaded the package from here https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/ (pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz) as **I want it as a local dependency since this is a portable plugin for Sublime Text 3**.

So I have `/MyPLugin/Crypto/` and Crypto looks good having the expected `__init__.py` files in the right places.

In `/MyPlugin/myplugin.py` I am trying to import AES like in the example (`from Crypto.Cipher import AES`). I have tried many combinations with dots and stuff but nothing seems to work.

How can I import AES from this relative Crypto folder?

Couple of the tries:

`from MyPlugin.Crypto.Cipher import AES` = ImportError: cannot import name AES

`import Crypto` = ImportError: No module named 'Crypto'

`import .Crypto` = SyntaxError: invalid syntax

PS I made a mistake - it is using **Python 3.3**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the library you are talking about is in your python path.  Information about modifying your python path [here](https://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html#modifying-python-s-search-path).  I'd try doing that.  Although, when you add a new library this usually happens.

Comment: Thanks, but this is a plugin for Sublime Text 3 so I cannot modify the users system I think, also I made a mistake this is for Python 3.3 I didn't realise sublime 3 bundles it's own version of Python now

Comment: Whenever you install a library, you have to modify the python path or python cannot access what you have installed.  You're modifying the python path, not the system path fyi

Comment: Also, try looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799990/sublime-text-plugin-adding-python-libraries